# RabbitMQ : maintain a "directory" of subscribers

Tags: rabbitmq, amqp

I have multiple applications talking together through an AMQP federation of several brokers.

Is there anyway for an application to create and maintain a list of all applications currently connected ?

I could send a "Who's there ?" message every few seconds and create the list from the replies, but is there any better (and more efficient) way to do that ?

## Edit :

My applications are written in C++, using Qt and QAMQP library.
For example, if applications A, B, C, D are running, I want to :

- A knows B, C, D are running
- B knows A, C, D are running
- etc...

And if a new application is started are one running application is terminated (normal exit or crash) other applications should have their lists updated.

The HTTP API should be an option, but is there any other ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure to understand your question.

BTW through the `HTTP API` you can get the consumer list as: `http://your_server:15672/api/consumers`

you have to enable the [management plugin](https://www.rabbitmq.com/management.html)

```
rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_management
```